# The substructure generated by a subset

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the following definition of a substructure generated by a set:

"For any subset A ⊆ X of an n-ary structure (X, µ), the family of subsets
X' ⊆ X containing A and closed under µ is nonempty: it contains, for
example X itself. By Exercise 38, their intersection is closed under µ. The
intersection is the smallest subset of X containing A with this property. It
will be denoted $\langle A\rangle$ henceforth. The corresponding substructure of (X, µ)
is called the substructure of (X, µ) generated by a subset A ⊆ X."

To put it in my own terms, the gist of the definition is that you want the smallest possible subset containing your set A that is also closed under the n-ary operation. I am currently trying to think of some examples where A is not equal to the set X in the substructure, and I was wondering what are some good examples of this?

Comment: Perhaps you can offer some more of your own reflections on this, what are some of the immediate examples that some to mind? Further, you have not offered the context for the quote you give above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the semigroup $\Bbb Z^+$ under the binary operation of addition. What is the smallest sub-semigroup containing the set $A = \{2\}$?

Comment: $2\mathbb{Z}$ Thank you.