# What is a substructure "generated" by a constant?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I was reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425562/defining-an-explict-structure) and I saw the answer in the comments regarding a substructure generated by 0. I have tried searching for a while online but clearly I'm not very good at it because I cant seem to find a clear answer as to what this means?

Thanks!

Comment: It's the same thing as the substructure generated by $\{0\}$. Are you familiar with the general construction of substructures generated by subsets?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Not really, the textbook I'm reading doesn't really talk about the word "generator" that I can find. I know what substructures are though

Comment: The substructure of a structure generated by a subset is just the smallest substructure which contains that subset; see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207164/the-substructure-generated-by-a-subse). So the substructure generated by $0$ (in whatever context is being considered) is the smallest substructure whose underlying set contains $0$. (This can be described more concretely in two ways: as the intersection of all substructures containing $0$ or as the closure of $\{0\}$ under the functions in the structure itself. Proving this equivalence is a good exercise.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I guess I just can't quite see this from a logic perspective. When you say "whose underlying set contains 0" does that mean the universe of the structure contains 0?

Comment: If $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure with universe $A$ and $X\subseteq A$, the substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $X$ is the smallest substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ whose universe contains $X$. *(Fine, technically we need to either allow empty structures or require that $X$ be nonempty, but oh well.)* Does that clarify things?

Comment: For example, the substructure of $(\mathbb{R}; +)$ generated by $\{0\}$ is just $(\{0\}; +)$, while the substructure of $(\mathbb{R}; +)$ generated by $\{1\}$ is $(\{1,2,3,...\}; +)$ (since we need to close $\{1\}$ under the function $+$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ahhh yes that clarifies everything thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{A}$ is a structure with universe *(or underlying set, or domain)* $A$ and $X\subseteq A$, then the *substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $X$* is$^1$ the smallest substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ whose universe contains $X$. (See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207164/the-substructure-generated-by-a-subset).)

We often abuse notation when talking about singletons: "the substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $a$" is just another name for the substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $\{a\}$. A similar abuse often happens with finite sets: "the substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $a_1,...,a_k$" is just another name for the substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $\{a_1,...,a_k\}$.

For example, taking $\mathcal{A}=(\mathbb{R};+)$, we have:

- The substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $0$ is just $(\{0\}; +)$.
- The substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $1$ is the somewhat more complicated $(\mathbb{N}_{>0};+)$. More generally, the substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $r\in\mathbb{R}$ is $$(\{kr: k\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}\}; +).$$
- The substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $3$ and $5$ is the smallest substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ with universe $\supseteq\{3,5\}$; this turns out to be $(\{3,5,6\}\cup\mathbb{N}_{>7}; +)$.

---

$^1$Technically this is only guaranteed to exist if $X\not=\emptyset$ or if we allow empty structures.